# Windows 7, SSD used space does not match total files space used

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have a 60GB SSD showing as 55GB in properties, installed with Windows 7 as c: drive.

I selected everything in C drive and went to properties and it says 37GB but when I right click on the C drive and go to properties it shows 48GB used.

I am trying to understand where the extra 11 GB is.

I have changed the  page file settings, and changed it to use 512mb, putting the main page file on an HDD disk but this made no difference after a reboot.

I have also made sure the recycle bin is empty.

Can anyone suggest what might be consuming the missing space?

Comment: It's likely shadow copies and system restore points.

Comment: Can I move those to another disk?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've been using linux for a while now, and haven't run into space issues in a long time.

Comment: No worries, thanks for replying though. Always wanted to learn and test out linux dont know where to start. Oh well, will save that for another thread :)

Comment: The easiest way to use a virtual machine. VirtualBox is free and easy to set up, and a great place to start trying new things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much ram do you have?

Windows 7 creates a hibernation file on c:\ . For example, my hibernate is 3G and the pagefile is 4G.

There are a few other hidden windows files/folders that will not show up when you select all in c:

A tool like http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner will help you clean up worthless files off your windows drive.

Comment: 16 gigs... I wanted to mention that in the OP, but was not sure if it was related as 11 gigs are missing but ram is 16

Comment: I am using linux to see the hibernate file, but if you go in explorer, file / folder settings and uncheck/check view all files, including hidden and system files, you will probably see the hibernation file in c:\

Comment: Can I move that to another disk thus freeing up space to install some virtual machines?

Comment: To completely turn off hibernation and clear the file, open an elevated prompt and type: powercfg -h off

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about what the effects of that are? I mean if I am running something (like rendering) and dont touch the pc for 2hrs does it just shut off because it cant hibernate or...?

Comment: @Ryan: A computer always has the option to *suspend to RAM* instead of using a hibernation file.  You only lose the ability to hibernate and the ability to use hybrid sleep, which is *suspend to RAM along a backup option of resuming from the hibernation file if your computer loses power." IMO, hibernation and hybrid sleep is only useful for desktops, which commonly do not have backup power, unlike a laptop.

Comment: @surfasb, Thanks for that! Will do as suggested and cross fingers ;)

Comment: @Ryan: No need to cross your fingers. Merely look up **ACPI Power States**.